# maven plugin to search?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

Are there any maven plugins that will search for artifacts? By artifactId would be great.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to plugin in artifactId and have it come back with full GAV's.

Comment: Artifactory provides several search types , you can use to search for artifacts in the Search module ,This can be integrated with maven ,  It can search using Maven GAVC too, To work with Artifactory you need to configure Maven to perform the following two steps:Resolve artifacts through Artifactory, Deploy artifacts to repositories through Artifactory. You can also use the Artifactory Query language.https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Query+Language https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Repository

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you specifically need a plugin? Nexus, now [powering Maven central](http://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch%7Cgav), has extremely good search functionality. IntelliJ provides really good maven gav completion, and Eclipse had done some decent work on it last I checked, too.

Comment: Yes, the groupId is changing on several internal projects. If I look in nexus I can find them by artifactId with the new groupId. However, this is kinda inconvenient. I'd rather just use a plugin in Eclipse to report findings, or fix them for me.